# Failed to run a script using IntelliJ plugin for docker deployment

Tags: intellij-idea, docker, intellij-14, coreos

**Environment**:
I'm using IntelliJ 14 to deploy docker containers into CoreOS (VM that created using Vagrant and VirtualBox) on my local machine.

**Setup**:
My Dockerfile should run a setup script:

```
ADD setup.sh /tmp/setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/setup.sh
RUN /tmp/setup.sh
```

**Docker deploy using IntelliJ**:
When running docker deploy (using IntelliJ), it builds an image, creating a container, but failed to run my script with the following error:

```
Step 5 : RUN /tmp/setup.sh

 ---> Running in cb36ed95ad50

[91m/bin/sh: 1: [0m
[91m/tmp/setup.sh: not found[0m
[91m
[0m
Error: The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
Failed to deploy 'Deployment: Dockerfile: Dockerfile': The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

**Docker deploy using Circle CI**:
I'm also using [circleci](https://circleci.com/) in order to continuously deploy docker containers on AWS EC2 (my staging and production environments).
When using [circleci](https://circleci.com/) with same docker file and setup.sh script it runs OK.

What is the difference?

Comment: What OS are you using for dev?

Comment: Windows on my local machine which run intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `91m` do not belong to the path to `/tmp/setup.sh`, then it may be an end of line encoding problem.

In ASCII, end of line (carriage return `CR`) may be printed as `m` or `^M` and square brackets `[` encoding is `91`.

In Windows, end of line is represented by the characters are `CR+LF` and in Unix only `LF`.

You may try to convert the `setup.sh` file format from Windows to Unix.
There are many tools that can do that for you. On Unix I usually use `dos2unix`. On Windows I usually use `notepad++`.

Here is how to run it on with `dos2unix`:

- On your CoreOS machine install package named dos2unix and run the following command:

  > dos2unix setup.sh

Here is how to use it with `notepad++`:

- On your Windows machine install [`notepad++`](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.8.html)

  > - Open `setup.sh` with `notepad++`
  > - Go to Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix/OSX Format
  > - Save the file

Run your docker deployment with the new `setup.sh` again and I hope it will solve your problem.